# Keep active menu item open in accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Joomla menu that uses jQuery to make it into an accordion menu. I have the accordion functionality working, but I am needing to keep the active sub menu item visible when a visitor navigates to a specific page. I have included the jQuery code and a snippet of the HTML for the sub menu. Joomla applies an "active" class to the parent and children li elements in the HTML and I am wondering if this could be used by jQuery to keep the accordion menu open.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.accordion li.parent a').on('click', function() {
            $('.accordion .first-level, .accordion .second-level').removeAttr('href');
            var element = $(this).parent('li');
            if (element.hasClass('open')) {
                element.removeClass('open');
                element.find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.find('ul').slideUp();
            } else {
                element.addClass('open');
                element.children('ul').slideDown();
                element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
                element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

<ul class="">
    <li class="item-164 active deeper parent">
        <a class="first-level" href="/projects/commercial" title="Commercial Projects" >
            <span>Commercial</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li class="item-230 active deeper parent">
                <a class="second-level" href="/projects/commercial/car-washes-and-gas-bars" title="Car Washes and Gas Bars" >
                    <span>Car Washes and Gas Bars</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="item-582 current active">
                        <a href="/projects/commercial/car-washes-and-gas-bars/squeeky-kleen-red-deer" >
                            <span>Squeeky Kleen Red Deer</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-252">
                        <a href="/projects/commercial/car-washes-and-gas-bars/squeeky-kleen-sylvan-lake" title="Squeeky Kleen Sylvan Lake" >
                            <span>Squeeky Kleen Sylvan Lake</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-253">
                        <a href="/projects/commercial/car-washes-and-gas-bars/squeeky-kleen-innisfail" title="Squeeky Kleen Innisfail" >
                            <span>Squeeky Kleen Innisfail</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-251">
                        <a href="/projects/commercial/car-washes-and-gas-bars/scottys-esso" title="Scotty's Esso Drayton Valley" >
                            <span>Scotty's Esso</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item-250">
                        <a href="/projects/commercial/car-washes-and-gas-bars/big-bucket-car-wash" title="Big Bucket Car Wash" >
                            <span>Big Bucket Car Wash</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you using accordion widget from jquery? there is a option called active where you can set what will be open at beginning

Comment: @Clyff No, I am using code from CSS Menu Maker that has been modified to meet my needs. Are you referring to the official jQuery API accordion widget?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry i'm not familiar with CSS Menu Maker.

Comment: Hey there, not sure if you found the solution you were looking for but CSS Menu Maker [**published this post recently**](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/how-do-i-keep-the-accordion-submenu-open/) on how to do this. I hope it helps!